# Add To do list or an item in calendar - outlook + SharePoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, outlook

I have a WebPart which is used to add new tasks to my employees. Whenever a new task has been added i want to send a mail to them. We have option for that SPUtility.Sendmail(...)

I would like to add this task to their outlook calendar or to do list. Is it possible? It has to be done within SharePoint site. I have configured outgoing email. internal@domain.com.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not Out of the Box.  I've written this for numerous customers, however, using the EWS Managed Api (1.2).  Via that, you can write an event receiver or workflow that will update user calendars.  Just make sure you're careful and thorough when configuring the security settings for the exchange server.

If you have any questions about this, please let me know.  And not to push my own plug, but if you'd like to simply buy this feature/code from my company, I'm sure we could arrange that cheaply.

Good luck!